# Only last record is displaying in Ajax sent from Struts action

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

This is my code to generate data table in JSP. In my Struts action class I've used list that has one object which contains two records but in my JSP its displaying only last record in the object

**Struts action class:**

```
 @ParentPackage("json-default")
        public class StrutsPaginationAction extends ActionSupport {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int iTotalRecords;
            private int iTotalDisplayRecords;
            private String sEcho;
            private String sColumns;
            private List<SmsDTO> aaData;
            private List<SmsDTO> personsList;
        DBCLass d=new DBCLass();

            public StrutsPaginationAction() {

                SmsDTO smsDTO=new SmsDTO();


                    **personsList=d.smsResult();**






                System.out.println(personsList.size());
                setiTotalDisplayRecords(personsList.size());

                setiTotalRecords(personsList.size());
                setAaData(personsList);

            }

            @Action(value = "/strutsPaginationAction", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json") })
            public String execute() throws Exception {
                return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
            }

            public List<SmsDTO> getPersonsList() {
                return personsList;
            }

            public void setPersonsList(List<SmsDTO> personsList) {
                this.personsList = personsList;
            }

            public int getiTotalRecords() {
                return iTotalRecords;
            }

            public void setiTotalRecords(int iTotalRecords) {
                this.iTotalRecords = iTotalRecords;
            }

            public int getiTotalDisplayRecords() {
                return iTotalDisplayRecords;
            }

            public void setiTotalDisplayRecords(int iTotalDisplayRecords) {
                this.iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords;
            }

            public String getsEcho() {
                return sEcho;
            }

            public void setsEcho(String sEcho) {
                this.sEcho = sEcho;
            }

            public String getsColumns() {
                return sColumns;
            }

            public void setsColumns(String sColumns) {
                this.sColumns = sColumns;
            }

            public List<SmsDTO> getAaData() {
                return aaData;
            }

            public void setAaData(List<SmsDTO> aaData) {
                this.aaData = personsList;
            }
        }
```

**My Ajax code:**

```jsp
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#example").dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": false,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sort": "phone",
            "sAjaxSource": "strutsPaginationAction",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "phone" },
                { "mData": "studentname" },
                { "mData": "ref" },



               /*  { "mData": "phone" },
                { "mData": "start_date" },
                { "mData": "salary" }, */

            ]
        } );

    } );

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 >Struts 2 pagination using DataTables<br><br></h2>
    <table width="70%" style="border: 3px;background: rgb(243, 244, 248);"><tr><td>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Ref</th>
                    <!-- <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th> -->
                </tr>
            </thead>       
        </table>
        </td></tr></table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with database code.... previously i was instantiate object inside loop that is the reason its repeated

```
 public ArrayList<SmsDTO> getReulst() {
            /*ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            ArrayList<SmsDTO> ar = new ArrayList<SmsDTO>();
            SmsDTO sms = null;
            try {

                conn = getConnection();
                String query = "select pt.P_MOBILE,st.S_FIRSTNAME,st.REF_ID  from parent_info pt join student_info st on pt.REF_ID = st.REF_ID  where st.S_CLASS_TO_JOIN = 10;";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                // extract data from the ResultSet
                while (rs.next()) {


sms = new SmsDTO();
-------------------

                    long phone = rs.getLong(1);
                    sms.setPhone(phone);
                    String student_name = rs.getString(2);
                    sms.setStudentname(student_name);
                    String ref = rs.getString(3);
                    sms.setRef(ref);
                    ar.add(sms);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    pstmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return ar;*/
    }
    }
```